# Android Picasso is not loading image when i use fit()

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

Without fit() it works fine.
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url.concat(featureImage)).into(imageView);

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.featureImage);
TextView textTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView textDetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail); 
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url.concat(featureImage)).fit().into(imageView);
textTitle.setText(title);
textDetail.setText(detail);
```

Comment: Show the error or Log report. for More detailing.

Comment: where is your fit() call?

Comment: i have edited my question please check once.

Comment: see,this issue already filed in github https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364

Answer (score 7):

- [fit()](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fit--) - Attempt to resize the image to fit exactly into the target ImageView's bounds.

So if you set **layout_width** or **layout_height** of your ImageView **"wrap_content"** and don't set minimal possible sizes, height or width of the view will be initially 0 and your image will be resized accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).centerCrop().fit()
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.bg_screen)
                            .error(R.mipmap.bg_screen)
                            .into(mImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: TRUE");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onError: TRUE");
                                }
                            });
```

your imageview in xml should like ,

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_movie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
```

Comment: image is clear but still i am not getting required size. Actually i want to display image in detail page .  I need image height = 300dp and width = scren width(which should be as per screen rotation). Is there any thing that can be managed in xml file

Comment: Nothing else. need to check your code stuff for that image blur issue.kindly accept as answer if applicable in your case . will fix your issue once you depict some of your code stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> Eventually the following code fulfilled my requirement.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url.concat(featureImage)).centerCrop().fit()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.nrum_logo)
            .error(R.mipmap.nrum_logo)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.i("Picasso", "onSuccess: TRUE");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.i("Picasso", "onError: TRUE");
                }
            });
```

My imageView:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/featureImage" />
```